# Develop App Like NetFlix Google TV

Tags: widget, google-tv, television

I want to develop an application like in netflix in the google tv. Problem is that I don't how to create the icon where user clicks and website opens same as netflix

Can anybody familiar with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to create a wrapper app so that it appears in the launcher? Have a look at this article by Motorola http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-For-Enterprise/Hybrid-Web-Android-Apps-Applying-an-Android-Wrapper-to-an/ba-p/21370. You'll also need a Google Play account to submit the app through and Eclipse to build the app in AND you'll need to remember the to set the android.hardware.touchscreen feature requirement false in the Manifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

I suggest you pay someone to do it for you.